# confirm dialog in angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, popup

On click of a delete button, I want to display a confirm dialog box with YES or NO option for the user to select using angular-ui or bootstrap.

Can anybody provide a sample for this feature.

Comment: you can use an ngDialog [link](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog), it is easy to use you provide `template`, `controller` for handling logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with angular2/typescript but i dont think it differs much with this sort of things.

This is the example i used for my project.

valor-software http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals

or else use this.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is what exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angualr-material for this feature.

Here are the examples

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material/angular_material_dialogs.htm

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog)
and example from documents

```
ngDialog.open({
preCloseCallback: function(value) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to close without saving your changes?')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```